# PySpark collectAsMap no key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I am saving keys and values in a variable using Spark's collectAsMap() method. Now I wish to return "null" or something else when the key isnt found. How can I do that?

Comment: How does the `DF` look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dict's get method.
It looks like: `dict.get(key[, default=None])`

It is often better practice to use this than an accessor because you can specify a default value if the key does not exist, which by default is `None`, meanwhile an accessor (like `dict[key]`)  will throw a KeyError

Comment: awesome! Exactly what i needed!